# Linux: shutdown message prompts right after reboot

Tags: linux

I have a server (debian etch) that sometimes prompts the following message (right after starting/rebooting the computer):

```
The system is going down on <time in past>
```

Running a `shutdown -c` results in:

```
Cannot find pid of running shutdown.
```

Because of this problem normal users can no longer login, only root access is possible.
Has anyone seen this problem or has anyone a suggestion for me? thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shutdown creates an `/etc/nologin` file when called to stop new (non root) users logging in once a shutdown is scheduled. Removing the file should allow users to login.

> If shutdown is called with a delay, it
>   creates the advisory file /etc/nologin
>   which causes programs such as login(1)
>   to not allow new user logins. Shutdown
>   removes this file if it is stopped
>   before it can signal init (i.e. it is
>   cancelled or something goes wrong). It
>   also removes it before calling init to
>   change the runlevel.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown